# With $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_ny_n}$, and $y_{n+1}={x_n+y_n \over 2}$, $n\geq 2$. Show that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} y_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $0<a<b$, $x_1=a>0$, $y_1=b>0$, $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_ny_n}$, and $y_{n+1}={x_n+y_n \over 2}$, $n\geq 2$. Show that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} y_n$.

I have considered the fact that $(y_n-x_n)^2>0$ implies that ${x_n+y_n \over 2}>\sqrt{x_ny_n}$. I'm not entirely sure how to prove this result. Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Arithmetic–geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see that $x_1=\frac{x_1+x_1}2<y_2<\frac{y_1+y_1}2=y_1$.  Thus, $x_1<y_2<y_1$ since $x_1<y_1$.

In the same manner, see that $x_1<x_2<y_2$.

You have already shown that $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_ny_n}<\frac{x_n+y_n}2=y_{n+1}$.

Putting all this together, you get

$$x_1<x_2<y_2<y_1$$

Prove with induction that we have the stronger statement:

$$x_1<x_2<x_3<\dots<y_3<y_2<y_1$$

Clearly, you can see $x$ is monotonically increasing while $y$ is monotonically decreasing and that they are bounded.  From this, it is clear that there **must** exist a limit.

Let us call the limits $X$ and $Y$.  From this, we see

$$Y=\frac{X+Y}2\implies2Y=X+Y\implies X=Y\\\mathsf{or}\\X=\sqrt{XY}\implies X^2=XY\implies X=Y$$

Comment: Congrats, you understood my answer!

Comment: @mathguy ;)  I figured it would be worth writing it all out.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you for your answer. Forgive me, but I'm not entirely sure how to show that $x_1<x_2<y_2$ ("in the same manner"). Could you explain please?

Comment: @hungryformath ($x_2<y_2$ as you have already shown)$$x_1=\sqrt{x_1x_1}<x_2<y_2$$Can you take it from there?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I have, 
$x_1=\sqrt{x_1 x_1}< \sqrt{x_1 y_1} \stackrel{\text{?}}{<} \sqrt{y_2 y_2}=y_2$.
But I'm not sure why the second inequality holds. Clearly the first is via $x_1<y_1$, and I can see on a number line why-ish we get the second ($y_n$ is the midpoint of $x_1$ and $y_1$, but rigorously I cannot seem to get it. Btw thank you for your reply and original solution. I really like this method (over others I have seen).

Comment: *$y_2$, not $y_n$.

Comment: @hungryformath In essence, you are trying to show that $x_2<y_2$.  It requires showing that, from their definitions,$$\sqrt{x_1y_1}<\frac{x_1+y_1}2$$which is easily shown by squaring both sides.  After some manipulation, I think you should end up with the statement $(x_1-y_1)^2\stackrel?>0$ which is obvious.  This can easily be reproduced to the general case.

Answer (score 1):

First show that $x_n < y_n$ for all $n$, then use this to prove that $x_n$ is increasing and $y_n$ is decreasing. Also, they are bounded (why?) so both converge to finite limits, call them $X$ and $Y$. Taking limits, $Y = \dfrac{X+Y}{2}$ so $X=Y$.